# How to avoid helper functions being warned? " xxx defined but not used"

Tags: c++

I learnt from this post here to create helper functions in namespace.
['Helper' functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80619/helper-functions-in-c)

```
//stringhelper.hpp
namespace utility{
static std::string intToString(int integer)
{
    std::stringstream sstream;
    sstream << integer;
    return sstream.str();
}
static void toLowerCase(std::string& y)
{
    std::transform(y.begin(), y.end(), y.begin(), (int(*)(int))tolower);
}
}
```

I include this header but I got the following warning

```
'void utility::toLowerCase(std::string&)' defined but not used
```

Yes. I used intToString(int integer) but not toLowerCase(std::string&). I don't want to see those warning or divide one helper function per header.

Can anyone suggest a good solution? Should I just disable warning? Thank you

Comment: What is your compiler? Warnings and their enabling and disabling are compiler-specific.

Comment: it is GCC, of course. no other compiler would care.

Comment: Given the way you are using them (including from a header file so they have the same definition in each translation unit), it would make more sense to make them `inline` rather than `static`. Is there any particular reason that you wanted to give them internal linkage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the option to turn off that warning:

```
-Wno-unused-function
```

On a function-by-function basis, with GCC, you may define:

```
void whatever () __attribute__ ((unused));

void whatever () {
    stuff;
}
```

This tells GCC that the function is meant to possibly be unused.

See [compiler docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function%20Attributes) for more info on **attribute**

Comment: "OrgnlDave. This method works. However, when I want to combine the definition, compiler returns error of "attribute are not allowed on function definition". For example, this definition return error: 

 static void toLowerCase(std::string& y) __attribute__ ((unused)){
  std::transform(y.begin(), y.end(), y.begin(), (int(*)(int))tolower);
 }

Comment: The implementation of helper functions are written in header. I do not have seperated cpp file.

Comment: @Mickey it is OK, you can declare the signature and then implement it directly underneath if you want, just like what I showed

Comment: I have changed my header function same as your demonstration. Just curious. Can this 2 line joined together?

Comment: @Mickey I don't put a lot of thought into __attribute__ a lot in GCC since I generally write cross-platform code, but I don't think so. function attributes are meant for many things, for instance, forcing things to be inlined or not, so it makes sense for them to be in the declarations and not the implementations. but again I'm not an expert on it. from the documentation I can see no way to do so