# C++ string in classes

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors

I know this is quite a ridiculous question but this is quite confusing and irritating, as something that *should* work simply is not. I'm using Code Blocks with the GCC compiler and I am trying to simply create a string variable in my class

```
#ifndef ALIEN_LANGUAGE
#define ALIEN_LANGUAGE

#include <string>

class Language
{
    public:

    private:
        string str;
};

#endif
```

Strange enough, my compiler halts me with an error saying this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\...|11|error: `string' does not name a type|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

For some reason, it is unable to find the class "string" which for some reason, my main.cpp is able to detect "#include " while my language class is not able for some reason.

This is the main I wrote quickly just to see it main itself is able to see the string file:

```
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "alien_language.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`using namespace std;`

That's what's going on.

You don't have `std::` prefixing the string in your class. Everything in the standard library is in the namespace `std`.

It is generally regarded as bad practice to use `using namespace std;`, by the way. For more information on why and what to do instead, check out this question: [Using std Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace).

Comment: Thank you, I've completely forgot that string the std:: prefixing, I'm used to not putting using namespace std; in my class files, but doing so in my main.cpp

Answer (score 7):

The string class is defined in the std namespace. You should chenge the class to this:

```
class Language
{
    public:

    private:
        std::string str;
};
```

It is also possible, but not recommended to add this to the top of the header file:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Ah, someone _not_ recommending `using namespace std;`! +1

Answer (score 6):

string is in namespace std, and you need to qualify it fully inside your header file:

```
#include <string>

class Language
{
    public:

    private:
        std::string str;
};
```

Do not use `using namespace std;` or similar in header files.

Comment: why not to `using namespace std;` in header files?

Comment: nevermind, find the appropriate answer after googling: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/25538/
  
leaving these comments for future confusions

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to it as std::string;

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're missing the all-important (with a hint of sarcasm) `using namespace std;` line. Either add that in before your class, or explicitely use `std::string str`. I'd recommend against adding the `using namespace std;` line in a header file, as it would pollute the mainspace for any file that includes it.

Answer (score 0):

The `string` class in standard C++ is in `std` namespace. Write something like 
`using std::string;` in your header or fully qualify it as std::string in your header.

Beware that `using namespace std;` in header is a bad practice (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace)).