# Simple constructor with initializer list?

Tags: c++, constructor, ctor-initializer, undeclared-identifier

Below I've included my h file, and my problem is that the compiler is not liking my simple exception class's constructor's with initializer lists. It also is saying that `string is undeclared identifier`, even though I have `#include <string>` at the top of the h file. Do you see something I am doing wrong? For further explanation, this is one of my domain classes that I'm integrating into a wxWidgets GUI application on Windows.

Thanks!

#### Time.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// global constants for use in calculation
const int HOURS_TO_MINUTES = 60;
const int MINUTES_TO_HOURS = 100;

class Time
{
public:
   // default Time class constructor
   // initializes all vars to default values
   Time(void);
   // ComputeEndTime computes the new delivery end time
   // params - none
   // preconditions - vars will be error-free
   // postconditions - the correct end time will be returned as an int
   // returns an int
   int ComputeEndTime();
   // GetStartTime is the getter for var startTime
   // params - none
   // returns an int
   int GetStartTime() { return startTime; }
   // GetEndTime is the getter for var endTime
   // params - none
   // returns an int
   int GetEndTime() { return endTime; }
   // GetTimeDiff is the getter for var timeDifference
   // params - none
   // returns a double
   double GetTimeDiff() { return timeDifference; }
   // SetStartTime is the setter for var startTime
   // params - an int
   // returns void
   void SetStartTime(int s) { startTime = s; }
   // SetEndTime is the setter for var endTime
   // params - an int
   // returns void
   void SetEndTime(int e) { endTime = e; }
   // SetTimeDiff is the setter for var timeDifference
   // params - a double
   // returns void
   void SetTimeDiff(double t) { timeDifference = t; }
   // destructor for Time class
   ~Time(void);
private:
   int startTime;
   int endTime;
   double timeDifference;
};

class HourOutOfRangeException
{
public:
   // param constructor
   // initializes message to passed paramater
   // preconditions - param will be a string
   // postconditions - message will be initialized
   // params a string
   // no return type
   HourOutOfRangeException(string pMessage) : message(pMessage) {}
   // GetMessage is getter for var message
   // params none
   // preconditions - none
   // postconditions - none
   // returns string
   string GetMessage() { return message; }
   // destructor
   ~HourOutOfRangeException() {}
private:
   string message;
};

class MinuteOutOfRangeException
{
public:
   // param constructor
   // initializes message to passed paramater
   // preconditions - param will be a string
   // postconditions - message will be initialized
   // params a string
   // no return type
   MinuteOutOfRangeException(string pMessage) : message(pMessage) {}
   // GetMessage is getter for var message
   // params none
   // preconditions - none
   // postconditions - none
   // returns string
   string GetMessage() { return message; }
   // destructor
   ~MinuteOutOfRangeException() {}
private:
   string message;
};

class PercentageOutOfRangeException
{
public:
   // param constructor
   // initializes message to passed paramater
   // preconditions - param will be a string
   // postconditions - message will be initialized
   // params a string
   // no return type
   PercentageOutOfRangeException(string pMessage) : message(pMessage) {}
   // GetMessage is getter for var message
   // params none
   // preconditions - none
   // postconditions - none
   // returns string
   string GetMessage() { return message; }
   // destructor
   ~PercentageOutOfRangeException() {}
private:
   string message;
};

class StartEndException
{
public:
   // param constructor
   // initializes message to passed paramater
   // preconditions - param will be a string
   // postconditions - message will be initialized
   // params a string
   // no return type
   StartEndException(string pMessage) : message(pMessage) {}
   // GetMessage is getter for var message
   // params none
   // preconditions - none
   // postconditions - none
   // returns string
   string GetMessage() { return message; }
   // destructor
   ~StartEndException() {}
private:
   string message;
};
```

Comment: Yikes! Indentation is all skewed....will fix....sorry

Comment: You should consider using doxygen for your documentation. Your comments already have a lot of information, just add the doxygen markup and you'd have pretty complete HTML docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` is in namespace `std`, so you need to qualify it:  `std::string`.  The initializer list has nothing to do with the problem.

On an unrelated note, you might consider having your exception classes derive from one of the standard library exceptions, like `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: oh....I'm an idiot.....I was leaving out namespace std. I am ashamed to post this on SO. :( Thanks though.

Comment: If you care to read more, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace