# Why is "using namespace std" not recommended in a header file in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

I have read many times that even if using namespace std in header file is legal, it can have catastrophic consequences. Perhaps I don't understand what using namespace std is. Thank you.

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c

Comment: Asked and answered many, many times.

Comment: It's not considered good practice even other than in a headerfile. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace