# std::string vs string in c++

Tags: c++, string, std

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)
> [Using std Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace)

I've been hovering around a bunch of different forums and I seem to see this pop up every time and again. It's a very much beginner question.

I usually define a program with:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string x;
```

I see a bunch of code samples out there who define a string as

```
std::string
```

What is the purpose of this? Is it good practice or have some functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c). Also see [Why is std:: used by experienced coders rather than using namespace std;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469060/why-is-std-used-by-experienced-coders-rather-than-using-namespace-std).

Comment: i done a search but didnt find those questions.apolgoies everyone.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As the other answer already stated, using `std::` is necessary unless you import either the whole `std` namespace or `std::string` (see below).

In my opinion it's nicer to use `std::string` instead of `string` as it explicitly shows that it's a `std::string` and not some other string implementation.

If you prefer to write just `string` though, I'd suggest you to use `using std::string;` instead of `using namespace std;` to only import the things into the global namespace that you actually require.

Comment: What is unsaid here, that is actually the payoff, is after declaring `using std::string;`, you can just write, e.g. `string s="foo";`.

Answer (score 22):

The full name of `string` is `std::string` because it resides in `namespace std`, the namespace in which all of the C++ standard library functions, classes, and objects reside.

In your code, you've explicitly added the line `using namespace std;`, which lets you use anything from the standard namespace without using the `std::` prefix.  Thus you can refer to `std::string` (the real name of the string type) using the shorthand `string` since the compiler knows to look in `namespace std` for it.

There is no functionality difference between `string` and `std::string` because they're the same type.  That said, there are times where you would prefer `std::string` over `string`.  For example, in a header file, it is generally not considered a good idea to put the line `using namespace std;` (or to use any namespace, for that matter) because it can cause names in files that include that header to become ambiguous.  In this setup, you would just `#include <string>` in the header, then use `std::string` to refer to the string type.  Similarly, if there ever was any ambiguity between `std::string` and some other `string` type, using the name `std::string` would remove the ambiguity.

Whether or not you include the line `using namespace std;` at all is a somewhat contested topic and many programmers are strongly for or strongly against it.  I suggest using whatever you're comfortable with and making sure to adopt whatever coding conventions are used when working on a large project.

Comment: The full name of `string` is `::std::string`, but nobody uses that.

Answer (score 6):

As [ssteinberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642681/ssteinberg) said it is the same. But only syntactically.

From my experience, it is more useful to either use the full name

```
std::string
```

wherever you need it, or add an explicit

```
using std::string;
```

in the beginning of your source file.

The advantage is that in this way the dependencies of your source file are more observable. If you add a

```
using namespace std;
```

it means that your code may depend on anything within that namespace.

Answer (score 3):

If they are not `using` the `namespace std`, then they have to specify what namespace string belong to by using `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `using namespace std;` before your code it is the same.