# C++: Templates in Header files are destroying me

Tags: c++, templates, header

I'm fluent in Java, but very new to C++. I'm definitely not understanding what is wrong -- at all.

Here's the code:

```
// Sort_Search.h
#ifndef SORT_SEARCH_H
#define SORT_SEARCH_H  

using std::vector;

template<typename T> void printVector(vector<T> &list);

#endif



// Sort_Search.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

template<typename T>
void printVector(vector<T> &list) {
    // print every member of the list
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)list.size(); i++) {
        // insert a comma where needed
        if(i != 0)
            cout << ", ";
        cout << list[i];
    }
}
```

I keep getting the same errors:

> sort_search.h(6): error C2182: 'printVector' : illegal use of type 'void'
>
> sort_search.h(6): error C2998: 'int printVector' : cannot be a template definition

There are more templates causing similar errors in the same files. I figured if I can fix one, I'll figure out how to fix the rest. I've tried every single thing I can think of.

Thanks so much for any help. I'm going crazy over here. haha.

Comment: Also read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html#faq-35.12) FAQ.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass `list` by value, that is, make a copy of the list just to print its elements and then get rid of the copy again? I suggest you change the signature to `template <typename T> void printVector(const std::vector<T>& list);`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the header, you need to provide the namespaces.

```
template<typename T> void printVector(std::vector<T> list);
//                                    ^^^^^
```

---

There are several things you need to consider:

1. In C++, parameters (except arrays) are always passed as *value type* if you don't specify it, unlike Java where every objects are passed as reference type. That means, if the function signature is `printVector(std::vector<T> list)`, the list will be **copied** when feed into `printVector`. This is often undesirable. Therefore, you need to change it to pass by *reference* by adding an `&` to the type:

   ```
   template<typename T> void printVector(std::vector<T>& list);
   //                                                  ^
   ```

   but making it a reference means modification of `list` inside `printVector` will be propagated out. You often don't want to accidentally modify the list. This can be enforced by making the parameter a `const`ant:

   ```
   template<typename T> void printVector(const std::vector<T>& list);
   //                                    ^^^^^
   ```

   (Making it a const-reference also have the advantage that it can accept rvalues.)
2. Also unlike Java, in C and C++ `#include` does not know if you have included the header once before. `#include` is simply a "copy-and-paste" mechanism. That means, if somehow the compiler sees

   ```
   #include "Sort_Search.h"
   ...
   #include "Sort_Search.h"
   ```

   then 2 copies of `printVector` will be defined, and that leads to compiler error. This is possible if two different headers `a.h` and `b.h` includes `Sort_Search.h` and some source file include both `a.h` and `b.h`. To avoid this, we always need to provide [an *#include guard*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) which prevents the file to be included more than once:

   ```
   #ifndef SORT_SEARCH_H_m6f2kyhdncxflxr
   #define SORT_SEARCH_H_m6f2kyhdncxflxr
   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   template<typename T> void printVector(const std::vector<T>& list);

   #endif
   //^^^^
   ```
3. A `vector<T>` is not a built-in type, so you need to `#include <vector>` to let the compiler knows the existence of such type.

   ```
   #ifndef SORT_SEARCH_H_m6f2kyhdncxflxr
   #define SORT_SEARCH_H_m6f2kyhdncxflxr

   #include <vector>
   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   template<typename T> void printVector(const std::vector<T>& list);

   #endif
   ```
4. Finally, a [template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(programming)) is implemented differently than generics in Java or C#. It is like an AST-level copy-and-paste mechanism. Every time you call `printVector`, the compiler will determine what `T` is (say, `int`), and then create a new function by replacing every `T` by `int`.

   Because of this, the implementation of a template cannot be separated from the declaration. Or, the implementation is *part of the* declaration. Therefore, for correctness, the `printVector` have to be moved into the header:

   ```
   #ifndef SORT_SEARCH_H_m6f2kyhdncxflxr
   #define SORT_SEARCH_H_m6f2kyhdncxflxr

   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>

   template<typename T> void printVector(const std::vector<T>& list) {
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++ i) { ... }
   }

   #endif
   ```

   Or, if you still want to separate the `.cpp` from `.h`, you could **include the `.cpp` from the `.h`**:

   ```
   #ifndef SORT_SEARCH_H_m6f2kyhdncxflxr
   #define SORT_SEARCH_H_m6f2kyhdncxflxr

   #include <vector>

   template<typename T> void printVector(const std::vector<T>& list);

   #include "Sort_Search.cpp"
   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   #endif
   ```

   ```
   // Sort_Search.cpp:
   #include <iostream>
   template<typename T> void printVector(const std::vector<T>& list) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you.
Would I be able to do something like:

`using namespace std;
#include "Sort_Search.h"`

in the main .cpp instead of std:vector ?

Comment: @Skinner927: You might want to read something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace) first.

Comment: @Skinner927: No. Headers should avoid assuming the files they're included in will have declared, included, or defined anything in particular before including the header. And `using namespace std;` is not widely considered good C++ practice, making that particular assumption even worse.

Comment: @beduin: `std::vector` is not a type. You can't `typedef` it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've read that `using namespace std;` is frowned upon. I'm taking a class at school and that's what the instructor uses but I'll be sure to change my ways! 

Is there a problem with declaring `using std:vector;` in the header and .cpp ?

Comment: @KennyTM: Yeah, my fault. I have deleted my comment)

Comment: @Skinner927: A very big problem: `using` declarations, like everything else, propagates from the header to the file it's included in, polluting the namespace and possibly surprising the person including it. The key thing to understand is that `#include` in C++ is quite literal: you're telling the compiler to take every byte of the header file, dump it in your cpp file, and then compile the result. The header is not a separately compiled entity, making it quite different from the sort of library modules you may be used to in languages like Java.

Comment: Java does not have pass by reference, only [pass by value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm). To contrast, C# can pass by reference if you use the `ref` keyword.

Comment: @KennyTM: Thank you for that extremely informative post. I had a feeling that my problems were coming from the fact that the implementation and declaration of the template cannot be separate, but I could not find anything specifically saying you couldn't in my text book. 

My problems have arisen from my instructor defining the template prototypes in a header file, I then though that I needed to make a corresponding .cpp file. 

Thanks so much for the help! I can now finish this project and get some sleep. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your life a million times easier and define all of your template functions / classes inline. There is no benefit to having a separate .h and .cpp file as both need to be included at compile time anyway so you get nothing but pain for splitting them up.

Answer (score 1):

What's actually wrong with your sample is the missing `#include <vector>` directive in Sort_Search.h. The remarks posted by others are also correct, of course.