# Cout doubles without cutting variables

Tags: c++, iostream

Here is some "pseudo" c++ code

```
double var = 5.5;
cout << var << endl;
double var2 = 6.0;
cout << var2 << endl;

5.5
6
```

The problem is that some code might expect that it's 6.0. Does someone has an idea how to change the output stream.

Okay here is some example code i tried

```
 double t = 6.0;
  while (t > 0.1) {
    t = t - 0.1;
    cout << setprecision(2) << t << endl;
  }
```

The output is

```
5.9
5.8
...
5.2
5.1
5
4.9
4.8
4.7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::setprecision` along with `std::fixed`:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << var2 << std::endl;
```

See demo : http://ideone.com/Arz85

Only `std::setprecision(1)` would not work. You've to use `std::fixed` as well.

Don't forget to include this:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

---

I guess you've written `using namespace std` in your code. If so, then don't do that. Write fully qualified names, such as `std::cout`, instead of `cout`. See these topics:

- [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)
- [Using std Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace)

Comment: Thanks this made. Especially the fixed() one was important!

Comment: I agree that using namespace std is bad here, but it really helps to be able to read the code, at least from my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Use ios_base flags, take a look at the C++ [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/%20reference).