# Calculating a Sum with C++

Tags: c++, sum, series

I wrote the following code to sum the series `(-1)^i*(i/(i+1))`. But when I run it I get `-1` for any value of n.

Can some one please point out what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 1.0;
    int n = 5.0;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        sum = (-1)^i*(i/(i+1));

    cout << "Sum" <<" = "<< sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the `^` operator does? Are you trying to perform an exclusive-or operation, or are you trying to perform exponentiation?

Comment: And why do you assign a floating point to an integer? (`int i = 1.0`)

Comment: well first your setting sum every single pass of the loop and not adding to the previous value of it. second ^ does not raise a power like you would think. check out the c math library. and watch out for implicit casts that happen when you divide into a fraction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Problem #1:** The C++ `^` operator isn't the math power operator. It's a bitwise XOR.

You should use `pow()` instead.

**Problem #2:** 
You are storing floating-point types into an integer type. So the following will result in [integer division (truncated division)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html):

```
i/(i+1)
```

**Problem #3:** 
You are not actually summing anything up:

```
sum = ...
```

should be:

```
sum += ...
```

---

A corrected version of the code is as follows:

```
double sum = 0;
int i = 1;
int n = 5;

for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    sum += pow(-1.,(double)i) * ((double)i / (i + 1));
```

---

Although you really don't need to use `pow` in this case. A simple test for odd/even will do.

```
double sum = 0;
int i = 1;
int n = 5;

for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    double val = (double)i / (i + 1);
    if (i % 2 != 0){
        val *= -1.;
    }
    sum += val;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, since all of his variables are `int`s it will do integer math, and `i/(i+1)` will always evaluate to 1, unless `i == 0` or `i==1`

Comment: That one was surprisingly hard to catch... took me a few min.

Comment: Forgot about  pow() it has been some time since I coded in C++

Comment: @Surfcast23 You don't actually need `pow()` in this case - since you're just trying to get `-1` or `1`.

Comment: @ybungalobill you are correct, I did the numerator and denominator backwards, been a rough friday for me

Answer (score 4):

You need too put sum += pow(-1,i)*(i/(i+1));

Otherwise you lose previous result each time.

Use pow function for pow operation.

edit : as said in other post, use double or float instead of int to avoid truncated division.

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```
((i % 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1)
```

instead of

```
std::pow(-1, i)
```

?

**Full answer:**

```
double sum = 0;
int i = 1.0;
int n = 5.0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    signed char sign = ((i % 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1);
    sum += sign * (i / (i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few problems:

1. ^ is teh bitwise exclusive or in c++ not "raised to power". Use pow() method.
2. Remove the dangling opening bracket from the last line
3. Use ints not floats when assigning to ints.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a few things wrong with your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

This is not directly related to your problem at hand, but don't ever say `using namespace std;` It introduces subtle bugs.

```
int i = 1.0;
int n = 5.0;
```

You are initializaing integral variables with floating-point constants. Try

```
int i = 1;
int n = 5;
```

```
sum = (-1)^i*(i/(i+1));
```

You have two problems with this expression. First, the quantity `(i/(i+1))` is always zero. Remember dividing two `int`s rounds the result.  Second, `^` doesn't do what you think it does. It is the exclusive-or operator, not the exponentiation operator. Third, `^` binds less tightly than `*`, so your expression is:

```
-1 xor (i * (i/(i+1)))

-1 xor (i * 0)
-1 xor 0
-1
```

Comment: what bugs does using namespace std cause, link?

Comment: Discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).

Comment: Thanks for the links regarding using namespace std.

Answer (score 1):

`^` does not do what you think it does. Also there are some other mistakes in your code.

What it should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main( )
{
    long sum = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int n = 5;

    for( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        sum += std::pow( -1.f, i ) * ( i / ( i + 1 ) );

    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To take a power of a value, use `std::pow` ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/)). Also you can not assign `int` to a decimal value. For that you need to use `float` or `double`.

The aforementioned `^` is a bitwise-XOR, not a mark for an exponent.

Also be careful of [Integer Arithmetic](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~smoler/x86text/lect.notes/arith.int.html) as you may get unexpected results. You most likely want to change your variables to either `float` or `double`.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code:

```
int sum = 0;
```

The intermediate results are not integers, this should be a double

```
int i = 1.0;
```

Since you will use this in a division, it should be a double, 1/2 is 0 if calculated in integers.

```
int n = 5.0;
```

This is an int, not a floating point value, no .0 is needed.

```
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

You've already initialized i to 1, why do it again?

```
sum = (-1)^i*(i/(i+1));
```

Every iteration you lose the previous value, you should use sum+= 'new values'

Also, you don't need pow to calculate `(-1)^i`, all this does is switch between +1 and -1 depending on the odd/even status of `i`. You can do this easier with an `if` statement or with 2 `for`'s, one for odd `i` one for even ones... Many choices really.