# How do you convert a string into an array of floats?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, floating-point

How would you convert a string, lets say: 
`string Numbers = "0.3 5.7 9.8 6.2 0.54 6.3";`into a float array, such as: `float Numbers[6] = {0.3, 5.7, 9.8, 6.2, 0.54, 6.3};`?

Comment: I did some searches and seemed to be pointed to strtok, but other searches seemed to be saying you'd need a more custom function. Maybe you can find a better answer on google than I did, if someone else doesn't answer here.

Comment: Yea, that was my idea. I was planning on trying to use `strtok()` to break it up into the individual strings, then use `atof()` to convert the strings to floats, (bear in mind I am a novice programmer) I was having issues breaking up the string.

Answer (score 15):

I would use data structures and algorithms from `std::`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>

int main () {
  std::string Numbers = "0.3 5.7 9.8 6.2 0.54 6.3";

  // If possible, always prefer std::vector to naked array
  std::vector<float> v;

  // Build an istream that holds the input string
  std::istringstream iss(Numbers);

  // Iterate over the istream, using >> to grab floats
  // and push_back to store them in the vector
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<float>(iss),
        std::istream_iterator<float>(),
        std::back_inserter(v));

  // Put the result on standard out
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ", "));
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't use `using namespace std`?

Comment: Yes. Add `using namespace std` can introduce bugs. An OK description of the problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c

Comment: @Sean: Read the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace) with the most upvotes (I recommend never using it).