# Converting a string into multiple ints

Tags: c++, string, int

Newbie question but I have a string that gets 3 numbers, such as:

> 144.3 432.3 532.3

Now I define 3 floats with

```
float x;
float y;
float z;
```

How can I put all the values inside of them? Where,

```
x = 144.3; 
y = 432.3; 
z = 532.3;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a string into an array of floats?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986091/how-do-you-convert-a-string-into-an-array-of-floats)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss("144.3 432.3 532.3");
float x, y, z;
ss >> x >> y >> z;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) standard library function.

```
std::string orbits ("686.97 365.24");
std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t

float mars = std::stof (orbits,&sz);
float earth = std::stof (orbits.substr(sz));
```