# I want to return a function of vector<Competition> but is told that Competition is undeclared and that I am using undefined class 'std::vector'

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am trying to build a vector using a function that I am calling `vector<Competition> CompPop()`. I want to return the vector info which is a type `vector<Competition>`. Below is my code for the function returning the vector and the header for my `Competition` class.

I'm getting the following errors (I'm using Visual Studio and the error message are very basic, leaving me guessing as to what I am actually doing wrong):

> -error C2065: 'Competition' : undeclared identifier
>
> 'CompPop' uses undefined class 'std::vector'
>
> 'Competition' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2133: 'info' : unknown size
>
> error C2512: 'std::vector' : no appropriate default constructor available
>
> error C2065: 'Competition' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'temp'
>
> error C3861: 'temp': identifier not found
>
> error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

---

```
    #pragma once

    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include "LogIn.h"
    #include "Registration.h"
    #include "Tree.h"
    #include "PriorityQueue.h"
    #include "Events.h"
    #include "Competition.h"
    using namespace std;

    vector<Competition> CompPop()
    {
        ifstream myfile("Results.txt");

        string line, tcomp, tleader, tfollower, tevents, tplacement;
        vector<Competition> info;
        istringstream instream;
        if(myfile.is_open())
        {
         int i = 0; // finds first line
         int n = 0; // current vector index
         int space;
         while(!myfile.eof())
         {
        getline(myfile,line);

        if(line[i] == '*')
        {
            space = line.find_first_of(" ");
                
            tleader = line.substr(0+1, space);
            tfollower = line.substr(space + 1, line.size());

        }
        else
        {
            if(line[i] == '-')
            {
                tcomp = line.substr(1, line.size());
                Competition temp(tcomp, tleader, tfollower);
                info[n] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!line.empty())
                {
                    line = line;

                    space = line.find_first_of(",");
                    tevents = line.substr(0, space);
                    tplacement = line.substr(space + 2,     line.size());
                    info[n].pushEvents(tevents,tplacement);
                }
                if(line.empty())
                {
                    n++;
                }
            }
           }
            }
        }
       else
       {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
       }

       myfile.close();

      return info;
    }
```

my Competition header:

```
    #pragma once

    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include "LogIn.h"
    #include "Registration.h"
    #include "Tree.h"
    #include "PriorityQueue.h"
    #include "Events.h"
    #include "CompPop.h"
    using namespace std;

    struct Competition
    {
         public:

     Competition(string compName, string lead, string follow)
     {
    Name = compName;
    Leader = lead;
    Follower = follow;
     }

     void pushEvents(string name, string place)
     {
    Events one(name, place);
    Eventrandom.push_back(one);
     }

     string GetName()
     {
    return Name;
     }

     string GetLeader()
     {
    return Leader;
     }

     string GetFollow()
     {
    return Follower;
     }

     string GetEvent()
     {
    return Event;
     }

     string GetScore()
     {
    return Score;
     }

      ~Competition();

     private:
   string Name, Leader, Follower, Event, Score;

   vector<Events> Eventrandom;
     };
```

Comment: You did include `<vector>` and are using `std::vector` somehow, right?

Comment: Do you have `#include <vector>`?  Most if not all of these errors stem from the fact that it doesn't know about vector and that its a templated type that defines the operator `[]`.

Comment: Yes, I did. Those were also the first things i checked :) Thanks for replying!

Comment: May we see the outside of the two blocks of code you've shown? It looks like the parts not shown are where the error most likely is.

Comment: Hi, chris, I've edited my posts show they show the entire headers. Thanks!

Comment: You're not using the contents of `CompPop.h` anywhere in your `Competition.h`. I'd remove that include for `CompPop.h`

Comment: Thank you so much! My errors are gone now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not `#include`ing the header for `Competition` in your source file.

As an aside, it also looks like you're doing `using namespace std;` in your header.  [This is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039).

**Edit based on updated info:**

This is a circular dependency issue.

If you simply forward declare `Competition` and declare `CompPop` in CompPop.h, and add the implementation of `CompPop` to a CompPop.cpp, you'll break the cycle.

So change CompPop.h to:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
struct Competition;
std::vector<Competition> CompPop();
```

Comment: Actually I did have the include the competition header in my CompPop.h
however, i also included CompPop.h in my competition header. I removed that and it seemed to do the trick. Does anyone know why that might have caused the issue?? Thanks!

Comment: It's not your headers that are the problem.  The issue is that you need `#include "Competition.h"` in the source file you've shown us.

Comment: Hi Fraser, the first is CompPop.h, I've edited my post above to show all my headers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing either includes or using statements.

Namely either missing your header for Component, or the one for std::vector, or both.

Also ensure you have either `using namespace std;` or `using std::vector;`

If this isn't the case, please provide more of your code so we can examine it fully.

[Edit] **Update based on your comments**
Are you using inclusion guards?

Comment: I've edited my posts to include my headers. As to inclusion guards, I don't think I am. I'll look it up now, but I don't know what they are. Thanks!

Comment: You were using inclusion guards, `#pragma once` is the simple way of doing it in Visual Studio.