# Global variable, redefinition; previous definition was 'function'

Tags: c++

I am trying to set a global variable, but it is giving me errors:

"exp" is ambiguous

'exp': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'

I've searched this problem up but no one seems to be facing the same issue.

```
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int level;
int exp;

void expBar()
{

    string bar = "--------------------";

    exp = 10;

    float progress = exp / bar.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < progress; i++)
    {
        bar[i] = '=';
    }

    cout << "[" << bar << "]";

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271889/global-variable-count-ambiguous

Comment: `std::exp()` exists and you bring it into the global namespace with `using namespace std;`. This, combined with fact that your `exp` is global variable makes the compiler confused.

Comment: @Steyrix Good find, probably better than mine.

Comment: exp stands for std::exp. The compiler thinks You created the variable exp with the same name as function std::exp. Do not write using namespace std;, where std::exp is defined. Instead of this write std::cout and std::endl; Or just rename Your variable: exp ->expvar, for example.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks dude, this worked I changed my variable from exp to xp. I didn't realise there was a pre-existing function called exp.

Comment: Defining `exp` would be UB whether `using namespace std;` was used or not, because `exp` is a reserved name.

Comment: @HarryBlackwood `I didn't realise there was a pre-existing function called exp` That's pretty much what the error message says :)

Comment: @eerorika • A quick search... I can't find reference to `exp` being reserved.  Where is that from?

Comment: @Eljay To be more specific, it is reserved in the global namespace where it was defined in the example. *"Each name from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with extern "C" linkage, both in namespace std and in the global namespace."*.

Comment: @eerorika • Thanks!  The global namespace is a minefield.

Comment: @Eljay There is apparently even a better matching rule: *"Each function signature from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a function signature with both extern "C" and extern "C++" linkage, or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace."*. Which I suppose is subtly important.