# Very basic C++ program issue - Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++

I just started teaching myself C++ on the Mac, and I have run into some issues.

I have written some code that allows the user to enter a number and when they hit enter, the number will be returned to the user.

Xcode will absolutely not have it though. Every time I try to run my code, it says that there is an issue with the `cin>> thisisanumber;` code.

The error comes up and says

`Invalid operands to binary expression.` **Error is on line 10.**

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int thisisanumber();

   cout << "Please enter a number: ";
   cin  >> thisisanumber;
   cin.ignore();
   cout << "You entered"<< thisisanumber <<"\n";
   cin.get();
}
```

Comment: The `cin.ignore()` there is normally unnecessary. You might as well just have two `cin.get()` side by side for the pause to work. `cin.sync()` doesn't have guaranteed behaviour, but it's one to look into for an always-working pause if your compiler implements it with the expected behaviour.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace), which talks about that usage of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: I just want to say that for your first question, this is very good. You've separated the error line, told us what error you're getting, and provided an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for us to use. One note about your wording is that you mean *Every time I try to* ***compile*** *my code*... It can't be run until it's compiled first, and this is a compiler error, as opposed to a runtime error such as a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've fallen victim to the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), which means `thisisanumber` is being treated as a function. Take out the parentheses and you should be fine:

```
int thisisanumber;
```

Also consider making it a bit more readable, such as `thisIsANumber`. If you ever need to know it, `thisIsANumber` uses the *camel-case* naming convention.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your variable without brackets, like

```
int thisisanumber;
```

With brackets, it is interpreted as a function, and a function can't be passed as a parameter to the `>>` operator.

Comment: Good on you for not saying `operator<<` too. It actually can work with that, which might not be expected: http://ideone.com/TJ3rJ

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the so called [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Basically everything, which could be parsed as a function declaration will be parsed as such. Therefore the compiler will interpret `int thisisanumber();` as a declaration of a function `thisisanumber` taking zero arguments and returning an `int`. If you consider this behaviour the problems with `cin>>thisisanumber;` should be somewhat selfevident.

If you remove the parantheses, changing the variable declaration to `int thisisanumber;`, your program should behave like you'd expect it to with `thisisanumber` being a variable of type `int`.

You might however reconsider your naming conventions, `thisisanumber` isn't exactly readable. I would suggest going with `this_is_a_number`, `thisIsANumber` or `ThisIsANumber`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int thisIsANumber;
```

try making it variable declaration because what you wrote has been interpreted as function.

Answer (score 0):

delete () after `thisisanumber`, because () after `thisisanumber` means that it's a function, when it's not.