# error using Xcode C++ when trying to use global variable

Tags: c++, xcode, global-variables

I'm begginer in C++ using Xcode.
I get error using Xcode C++ when trying to use declared global variable.
Here is example code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int count ;

int main()
{
    count=1;     // reference to 'count' is ambiguous

    cout << count;  // reference to 'count' is ambiguous

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an STL algorithm named [`std::count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) and as there is a `using namespace std;` directive the compiler now has two available `count` symbols to choose from: remove the `using namespace std;` and use `std::cout`.

See [Using std Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace) for further reading.

Comment: Everytime someone says `using namespace std;`, god eats a baby kitten.

Comment: Thanks, i've uderstood that i didn't know about STL algorithm named std::count(). I just learning global variables on simple examples. I've changed the variable's name to "count1" and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the `using namespace std;` or qualify the use of your variable `::count`:

```
int main()
{
    ::count=1;     // reference to 'count' is ambiguous

    cout << ::count;  // reference to 'count' is ambiguous

    return 0;
}
```

You get the ambiguity because of `std::count`.

Comment: Thanks, i've uderstood that i didn't know about STL algorithm named std::count(). I'm just learning global variables on simple examples. I've changed the variable's name to "count1" and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `using namespace std;` and change `cout` to `std::cout`. That using declaration pulls all of the standard library names into the global namespace, and their's an algorithm named `std::count` that's probably the source of the problem. In general, `using namespace std;` is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, i've uderstood that i didn't know about STL algorithm named std::count(). I'm just learning global variables on simple examples. I've changed the variable's name to "count1" and it works.