# namespace "std" has no member "sort"

Tags: c++, sorting, std

Trying to sort an array of Integers and after some googling, came across the solution using `std::sort` accompanied by this error: `namespace "std" has no member "sort"`.

Just to disqalify any qualms that I'm not using the std namespace, here is my header:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: You should never put `using namespace` in a header; not everyone who includes your header will want the global namespace polluted.

Comment: What is worse is that the global namespace is polluted by different things depending on what order header files where included in the past and future.

Comment: You should never put `#include "stdafx.h"` in a header either.  Although this is a very old problem. I am commenting for the purpose of helping future readers who see this question like I have 6+ years after it was asked.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

as stated in the [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) reference page.

See [Using std Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace), [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) and many other questions on SO discussing `using namespace std;`.

Comment: This resolved my error _namespace "std" has no member "sort"_ while attempting to compile with gnustl_static on the Android NDK. The reference to std::sort works in XCode and Visual Studio, but for the NDK I needed to add the include from this answer. Thanks!