# What is the difference of using std:: vs. not using it in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using std Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace)

I was just wondering if there was some reason to include std:: in some operations, like std::sort() for example. Is it because of possible overloading?

Comment: Because you don't want naming conflicts and to drag the entire `std` namespace into your code. Also this is a duplicate.

Comment: You use it when you want things in the `std` namespace to work, and not use it when you don't.

Comment: When someone sees your code and it has `std` in it, for example `std::string`, they would know that it belongs to the standard library. Whereas if someone saw `string` they wouldn't really know if it's a custom class you made or not. At least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the usually well known reasons of polluting the current namespace with unnecessary symbol names and readability there is a subtle another reasoning.

Consider the example of **[std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/)**,it is an standard library algorithm to swap two values. With **[Koenig algorithm/ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)** one would have to be cautious while using this algorithm because:

```
std::swap(obj1,obj2);
```

may not show the same behavior as:

```
using std::swap;
swap(obj1, obj2);
```

With ADL, which version of `swap` function gets called would depend on the namespace of the arguments passed to it.
If there exists an namespace `A` and if `A::obj1`, `A::obj2` & `A::swap()` exist then the second example will result in a call to `A::swap()` which might not be what the user wanted.

Further, if for some reason both:
`A::swap(A::MyClass&, A::MyClass&)` and `std::swap(A::MyClass&, A::MyClass&)` are defined, then the first example will call `std::swap(A::MyClass&, A::MyClass&)` but the second will not compile because `swap(obj1, obj2)` would be ambiguous.