# Not recognizing cout<< in my program?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm creating a program with multiple files and it's not recognizing cout<< in my tnode file. Can anyone locate where the problem is? Among other errors, I get this error "cout was not declared in this scope" in my node file. 
My main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout<<"hi";
    bst *list = new bst();
    return 0;
}
```

My BinarySearchTree file:

```
#ifndef bst_H
#define bst_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "tnode.h"



class bst
{
    public:

    bst()
    {
    root = NULL;
    }
void add(int key, char value) {
      if (root == NULL) {
            root = new tnode(key, value);
            return
      } else
            root->add(key, value);
            return
}






tnode *root;

};

#endif
```

My node file:

```
#ifndef tnode_H
#define tnode_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class tnode
{
public:
    tnode(int key, char value)
    {
                this->key = key;
                this->value = value;
                N = 1;
                left = NULL;
                right = NULL;
                cout<<"hi";
    }

void add(int key, char value) {
      if (key == this->key)
      {
            cout<<"This key already exists";
            return;
      }
      else if (key < this->key)
       {
            if (left == NULL) 
            {
                  left = new tnode(key, value);
                  cout<<"Your node has been placed!!";
                   return;
            } 
            else
            {
                  left->add(key, value);
                  cout<<"Your node has been placed!";
                  return;
            } 
      }
       else if (key > this->key)
       {
            if (right == NULL) 
            {
                  right = new tnode(key, value);
                  cout<<"Your node has been placed!!"; return;
            } 
            else
                  return right->add(key, value);
       }
      return;
}
        tnode* left;
        tnode* right;
        int key;
        char value;
        int N;

};




#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to do :

```
  using namespace std;
```

or

```
  std::cout
```

in your `tnode` file

But `using namespace std` is considered bad practice, so you'd better use the second way:

```
std::cout<<"Your node has been placed!!";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the namespace `std`. Either by `using namespace std` (which could go in .cpp files but never in .h files, read more about why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace)) or by using `std::cout` when calling it.