# How to look content of dynamic string array in c++ in VS debugger

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic

What is wrong in this code? I want to make a dynamic string array using string*, not collections, vectors, etc.

```
    int abc = 4;
string* abcdef = new string[abc];
for (int i = 0; i < abc; i++)
{
    cin >> abcdef[i];
}
```

It doesnot give any error but the data I enter is not appearing in locals box in VS2012.

Regards

Comment: Did you try adding a print (`cout <<`) loop to see what is stored in `abcdef`?

Comment: What a misleading naming scheme  ; )

Comment: It depends on your input data. Also, what is wrong with `std::vector<std::string>` btw?

Comment: Yes I added cout << in loop and the data is outputting, but why it donot appears in local box when debugging. Only string at 0 index appears in the locals box.

Comment: Did you expand the array in your debug windows?

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific in my question:  Did you do what biocomp recommended below (that is what I meant by "expand the array")?

Comment: Yes writing "abcdef, 4" in watch block worked, as biocomp said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, looks like your question is about VS debugger.

That's how VS debugger shows contents of a pointer. It doesn't know it's an array, so it just shows you what it points to - the first element. To show all of them in watch window type "abcdef, 4" (where 4 is size of an array, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

This works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int count = 4;
    std::string* stringArray = new std::string[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> stringArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "stringArray[" << i << "] = " << stringArray[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete [] stringArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Though, the better solution would still be:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> stringVector;
    std::cout << "Enter Strings (Ctrl-Z to finish):" << std::endl;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>(stringVector));
    std::copy(stringVector.begin(), stringVector.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Too much of `std::`, why not `using namespace std;`?

Comment: Unless we have C++11 supported compiler, it would fail with `std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>`

Comment: It avoids potential naming conflicts, especially when displaying code for someone else to use and not knowing what compiler they are using, which libraries they are including, etc.  I rarely use `using namespace [fill in the blank];`  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace

Comment: @thefourtheye:  There is nothing wrong with `std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>` in any version of C++.  The only change you would have to make in older versions is to separate the ">>" so the compiler does not try to treat it like an operator.  But that changes it to `std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string> >`.  The caveat to that:  `std::istream` did not properly support insertion and extraction of `std::strings` in most compilers prior to the new standard.

Comment: @ZacHowland Yes. That's exactly what I meant :)