# The Str method of Stringstream will not work. (concatenation of different types) (C++)

Tags: c++, string, output, stringstream

I'm brand new to C++ and I am trying to get a simple program up and running.

I'm using the Eclipse IDE ( C++ Version ) on a Windows System.

I am trying to concatenate an output statement, it will combine numbers and strings.

I know in Java, this was automatically done with the System.out.println() method.

What I was able to research was a nice way of implementing this in C++ is to use the string stream method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
```

...

```
string simpleOutput(){
  stringstream ss;

  int a  = 50; // for testing purposes 
  int b = 60;
  string temp = "Random";
  ss << a << b << temp;
  return string output = ss.str();


}
```

When I try compiling this code is get the following: "Method "str" could not be resolved.

I have yet to find a solution on any webpage.
T
Thank you!

Comment: @Psypher I am not at all sure what do you refer to. OP **does** use `stringstream`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Perhaps the `stringsteam` (missing an `r`)?

Comment: I see "stringsteam", not "stringstream", (or its waaay to late for me to be reading SO).

Comment: @Angew, WhozCraig right :) sorry for that. Still I believe this is only a typo.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev So do I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you're missing an include:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Also, you have a typo in the function, and your return statement is downright crazy. With these fixes, it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

string simpleOutput(){
  stringstream ss;

  int a  = 50; // for testing purposes 
  int b = 60;
  string temp = "Random";
  ss << a << b << temp;
  return ss.str();
}
```

[**See it live**](http://ideone.com/Zy35dR)

Comment: typing this exact code block still leads to Eclipse noting a bug: "Method "str" could not be resolved"

Comment: After an eclipse restart the code works, any idea why this happens?

Comment: @user2879101 Probably a stale cache of include files. BTW, "Method `str` could not be resolved." sounds more like a message from the IDE than from the compiler. Was it an actual compilation error, or the IDE's auto-completion complaining?

Comment: I believe this is coming directly from the Eclipse IDE, not the compiler itself.

Comment: @user2879101 Then you can as well ignore it, or solve it by purging the cache/restarting (like you did). IDE facilities get confused pretty easily - when in doubt, always ask your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `stringstream` you need to `#include <sstream>`. Also `stringstream` is defined in the `std` namespace, but from your code it seems you are using this namespace already. The other parts of the code seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are trapped by a forward declaration of `stringstream` - just `#include <sstream>`

Also use `std::stringstream`, `std::string` and `return ss.str()` (scrape that `string output`)

Further: Putting a using namespace::std in a  header (global scope) is no good.
See: [Using std Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! In my original code I'm using the std namespace, is there a reason I shouldn't be using it?

Comment: @user2879101 Have a look at the link

Comment: Nevermind, the code now works...after an eclipse restart. Any idea as to why an Eclipse restart is needed for code to compile properly?