# Using strings in C++ (search in string, split string, cout<< string)

Tags: c++, string, cout

I'm in charge of helping first year students with this program where we need to find a word in a string, a change it by another given word. i wrote it as such

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void changeWord(string &texto, string wordB, int pos, int sizeA)
{
    int auxi;
    string antes, depois;
    for(auxi = 0; auxi < pos; auxi++)
    {
        antes[auxi] = texto[auxi];
        cout<< "Antes["<< auxi<< "]: "<< antes[auxi]<< endl;
    }
    for(auxi = 0; auxi+pos+sizeA < texto.length(); auxi++)
    {
        depois[auxi] = texto[auxi+pos+sizeA];
        cout<< "Depois["<< auxi<< "]: "<< depois[auxi]<< endl;
    }
    cout<< "Antes: "<< antes<< "   Depois: "<< depois<< endl;
    texto = antes + wordB + depois;
    cout<< "Texto:"<< texto<< endl;
}

void findWord(string texto, string wordA, string wordB)
{
    int auxi;
    for(auxi = 0; auxi < texto.length(); auxi++)
    {
        cout<< "texto["<< auxi<< "]: "<< texto[auxi]<<"   wordA[0]: "<< wordA[0]<< endl;
        if(texto[auxi] == wordA[0])
        {
            int auxj;
            for(auxj = 1; auxj < wordA.length() && texto[auxi+auxj] == wordA[auxj]; auxj++)
            {
                cout<< "texto["<< auxi+auxj<< "]: "<< texto[auxi+auxj]<< "   wordA["<< auxj<< "]: "<< wordA[auxj]<< endl;
            }
            if(auxj == wordA.length())
            {
                changeWord(texto, wordB, auxi, wordA.length());
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string texto = "Isto_e_um_texto_qualquer";
    string wordA, wordB;
    cin >>wordA;
    cin >>wordB;
    findWord(texto, wordA, wordB);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect this to work, and to some degree it does what i wanted up until in function call to 'changeWord()' when i try to output both 'antes' and 'depois' strings.

These work inside their respective loops, printing to screen the expected char:

```
cout<< "Antes["<< auxi<< "]: "<< antes[auxi]<< endl;

cout<< "Depois["<< auxi<< "]: "<< depois[auxi]<< endl;
```

This does not:

```
cout<< "Antes: "<< antes<< "   Depois: "<< depois<< endl;
```

both 'antes' and 'depois' are printed as blank. In addition the program crashes when it gets to this line:

```
 texto = antes + wordB + depois;
```

I assume it is for the same reason it cant print them in the previous line.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be a nice idea to encourage your students to avoid `using namespace std`...

Comment: @Rook: why you think this is a nice idea? declaring `using namespace std;` makes the code more readable, isn't it?

Comment: @NirMH: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), it's not a massive decrease in readability and it prevents unintentional namespace collisions.

Comment: @NirMH if the namespace were any longer, perhaps. But 5 additional characters is a small overhead. In return, you avoid polluting the current namespace and remove a bunch of potential namespace collisions. For maintainers and debuggers (and SO answerers), it is obvious where the classes came from, and what they might be expected to do.

Comment: @NirMH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace also makes good points. Notably, `using namespace` isn't inherently bad, but it shouldn't be used carelessly.

Comment: @Rook: thanks for the comment - this was valuable knowledge indeed. i'll need to change my habits...

Answer (score 3):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

You declare both `antes` and `depois` as *empty* strings, then you do e.g.

```
antes[auxi] = texto[auxi];
```

It doesn't matter what index you use, it will still be *out of bounds* for the empty string `antes`.

In that specific loop, you start the indexing from zero, so you could append instead:

```
antes += texto[auxi];
```

Or instead of the loop use the [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function:

```
antes = texto.substr(0, auxi);
```

And not to talk about the existing [`replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) function.

Comment: You know.. i thought about this... but i didnt think this would be ok, since texto[auxi] would be char and not string... im not totaly confortable with c++ yet... still bound by some of the C implementations.

Answer (score 2):

> we need to find a word in a string, a change it by another given word.

May I suggest that you use the built in features of `std::string` to do the hard work for you?

```
std::string s = "a phrase to be altered";
std::string to_replace = "phrase";
std::string replacement = "sentence";

size_t pos = s.find(to_replace);

if (pos != std::string::npos)
    s.replace(pos, to_replace.length(), replacement);
```

Comment: This exercize is exactly to teach the students how to perform this without those features... par of the teacher's course or something... I do intend to show them this.. but i must be able to explain to them how to do without it

Comment: I've never understood this whole "teaching C++ minus the libraries and all the good language features" thing. Why not just teach C instead?

Comment: My thoughts exactly... go figure... as far as i know, this course was supposed to be in C.. i suppose it has something to do with the reasoning involved