# Trouble running C++ through terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, terminal

I wrote the following code after using "gedit take_input.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
cout<<"please enter your name (followed by 'enter')\n";

string file;

cin >> file;

cout<<"hello" << file << " ! welcome to ilinux, where innovation is a promise\n";
}
```

However, when I used "g++" to convert my human-readable code into object code (writing `g++ take_input.cpp -o take_input`), the terminal returns with a result similar to this:

```
take_input.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
take_input.cpp:5:1: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
 cout<<"please enter your name (followed by 'enter')\n";
 ^
take_input.cpp:5:1: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from take_input.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:61:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
   extern ostream cout;  /// Linked to standard output
                  ^
take_input.cpp:7:1: error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope
 string file;
 ^
take_input.cpp:7:1: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iosfwd:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from take_input.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stringfwd.h:62:33: note:   ‘std::string’
   typedef basic_string<char>    string;   
                                 ^
take_input.cpp:9:1: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
 cin >> file;
 ^            ^
take_input.cpp:9:8: error: ‘file’ was not declared in this scope
 cin >> file;
take_input.cpp:9:1: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from take_input.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:60:18: note:   ‘std::cin’
   extern istream cin;  /// Linked to standard input
                  ^
take_input.cpp:9:8: error: ‘file’ was not declared in this scope
 cin >> file;
        ^
```

Could you tell me what the reason is?

Comment: You have to write `std::cout`, because it's in the `std` namespace.

Comment: `cout` does not live in the global namespace but in `std`, thus you either have to `using namespace std;` or write `std::cout`

Comment: btw you can be happy that you were not allowed to post pictures. I am pretty sure you would get even more downvotes if you did so. Pictures are not copy/pasteable, thus when you have some code, always put is as text not as picture.

Comment: I don't get it. Why was my question downvoted? Could anyone explain? New to StackOverflow here.

Comment: Add `using namespace std;` after your include files. This will also do the trick.

Comment: @SadmanSakib _"I don't get it. Why was my question downvoted?"_ Because you have shown very low research efforts. This is already covered by very basic tutorials and C++ text books.

Comment: @Nivetha [Please stop teaching this to beginners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks man. Will be careful next time :)

Comment: @SadmanSakib De nada. You might also go through [The tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) again, and read the articles available in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors that you are getting are because the `cout` is not in the global namespace rather it is in `std` namespace.

Well instead of writing

```
using namespace std;
```

after `#include <iostream>` try using:

```
using std::cout;
```

since using first option is a bad practice. You can refer to [Why is using namespace std is a bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
For benefits of using `using std::cout` refer [Using std namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace)

Also you can use `std::cout` everywhere if you don't want to use `using std::cout`.

Answer (score 3):

Just read the error messages that you compiler gave you. The problem is that

> ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope

And the "suggested alternative" is `std::cout`. Same goes for `string` vs. `std::string`.

Note that generally, things belonging to the standard library need to be qualified with `std::` to be found.

You also need to `#include <string>` to use `std::string` btw.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler gives you the answer on line 7: Since you're not using the `std` namespace, you have to prepend `std::` to your `cout` and `cin` calls.

Answer (score -2):

Just add

```
using namespace std;
```

after `#include <iostream>`

Try this out.

Comment: I did not downvote because this is not wrong, but [please do not teach that to beginners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Could you explain why? I am a beginner too and I didn't quite catch your answer. Could you clarify?

Comment: @RafizSalehinSejim IMHO, it is not a mistake and for small programs it can be completely fine to `using namespace std;`. However, one should be aware of potential problems. Actually, I saw this practice in many books and talks. It might be ok for small example snippets, but often they miss to mention that there are good reasons not to do it.

Comment: @RafizSalehinSejim `using namespace std;` is not the ultimate evil. If you e.g. need to present short code snippets (like when you give a talk), I personally still do not like it, but it won't cause harm. One should however understand the dangers, something beginners usually can't. Thus I say: Do not tell them to do this.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks a lot! I promise I won't