# Question regarding 'using namespace std'?

Tags: c++

Recently i've noticed that if I don't include the 'using namespace std' in my program and just use 'std::cout' or 'std::endl' then my program still compiles just fine? Therefore if I use the 'std::' prefix is it even necessary to include the 'using namespace std'? Does the 'std::' prefix call the using namespace std? If someone can clear this up for me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it's a duplicate of this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace

Comment: `std::stuff` just uses `stuff` from namespace `std`.

Comment: You may also benefit from getting a good [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). That should definitely clear any all confusion you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: If you never use `using namespace std;` you'll be much happier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using std Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace)

Comment: None of these proposed duplicates actually say what `std::` means, which seems to be the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, `::` is called the "scope resolution operator", so `std::cout` means "The variable `cout`, which can be found inside `std`".

The `using namespace std;` directive means "For any name you can't find, also try looking it up in `std`". Thus, if you explicitly say `std::cout` (and equivalent for everything else in the `std` namespace), then you don't need `using namespace std`.

---

As others have said, it's usually considered bad style to use `using namespace std;`, because a lot of the names in `std` are things you might want to use elsewhere, for example [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). A compromise option is to instead say `using std::cout;`, which will tell the compiler to look for `cout` in `std` but not anything else.

There's debate about whether to say `using std::cout` or just write `std::cout` everywhere you need it in your main C++ file, but most people believe that you should rarely if ever use `using namespace`. If you're writing a header file, though, you should *never* use a `using` directive at the top level because then *every file* which includes yours will get it, and they might want to use different names.

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

```
using namespace std;
```

You're telling the program that anything that it can't find should be in the namespace std. For larger programs, this is a problem because you might be using multiple namespaces with functions that have the same name, so it's best to use `std::cout` for larger programs.