# How to use structured binding in an array passed as arg to some function?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to decompose an array of 2 integers given to a function into `x, y`

It doesn't work when using `int init[2]` as a parameter. But it does when I change it to `int (&init)[2]`.

```cpp
vector<vector<State>> Search(vector<vector<State>> board,
                             int init[2], int goal[2]) {
  auto [x, y] = init;
}
```

What does `(&init)` mean here? And why it doesn't work when using `int init[2]`?

Comment: [Don't do `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int (&init)[2]` is a reference to an array of two integers. `int init[2]` as a function parameter is a leftover from C++'s C heritage. It doesn't declare the function as taking an array. The type of the parameter is adjusted to `int*` and all size information for an array being passed into the function is lost.

A function taking `int init[2]` can be called with an array of any size, on account of actually taking a pointer. It may even be passed `nullptr`. While a function taking `int(&)[2]` may only be given a valid array of two as an argument.

Since in the working version `init` refers to a `int[2]` object, structured bindings can work with that array object. But a decayed pointer cannot be the subject of structured bindings, because the static type information available only gives access to a single element being pointed at.

Comment: Thanks!! I got it :)