# Java packages vs. C++ libraries

Tags: java, c++, package

In `Java`, there is what is called `package`. Does `library` in `C++` represent the same meaning, especially in terms for example of containg relative classes and the use of protected members?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how C# libraries work, but protected member are indeed visible from within the package and each package defines a separate namespace for class names, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @biziclop. I'm actually asking about C++ not C#.

Comment: @user588855 It turns out I can't even read. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are different dimensions of what a `package` means in Java. As a container that differentiates the names of the classes inside from the names of classes in other packages, its equivalent would be c++ `namespaces`.

As a unit that guarantees access to non-private members to classes in the same block, there is no equivalent in C++. The access level granted to a class is independent of the namespace where the class is defined.

As a way of ordering your sources in the disk, there is no equivalent, the C++ language has no requirements on how the code is stored in files.

Regarding c++ libraries, that is closer to `jar` files in Java. They bundle different classes that share some relation. A jar can contain more than one package, and more than one jar can contain classes from the same package. Similarly with libraries, they can contain classes from different namespaces and/or different libraries can contain classes from the same namespace.

Answer (score 8):

The closest to Java packages are [namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) in C++.

They can be nested into one another, and you need to specifically declare that you are `using` them or a part of their contents. However, they do not enforce any physical file hierarchy like Java packages do.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking I think that namespaces in C++ provide the same semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is more related to namespaces in C++. 
Java and C++ both use libraries. Library can be any independent set of classes[probably a framework] which can be accessed in our code.

Answer (score 0):

External Libraries are there in both Java and C++. Just the formats vary, .jar in Java and .dll/.so in C++.

Purpose of Packages and Namespaces are different from Libraries. They avoid running out of names by allowing user to logically group the source.

Answer (score 0):

A `package` in Java is a namespace for classes, interfaces and enums. Package name, a dot and the classname form the *fully qualified classname* of a class:

```
com.example.hello.HelloWorldApplication
^--packagename--^ ^-----classname-----^
```

The dots in the package name have a different meaning then the dot between the names: the first two dots of this example are *part of the package name*, the last one is a separator.

This should be kept in mind, because there's a common misunderstanding regarding package names: just because the names can be mapped to a hierarchical folder structure, some people think, package names have a hierarchy too - which is not the case: `hello` is not a "subpackage" of `example`!

But, to create a simple mapping to folders and files, a classloader can simply take the *fully qualified* class name, replace all dots with a slash and append `.class` to get a relative path to a class file.

But note again, that a folder/file mapping is not required t load classes - we can invent a class loader that gets classes from a database or a remote service - a folder/file mapping wouldn't make any sense in that case.