# Tidying up my namespacing in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have the namespaces like so:

```
namespace Jimmyt1988
{
    namespace PlatformGame
    {
        namespace Helpers
        {
        }
    }        
}
```

I'd be just as happy to do something like this:

```
namespace Jimmyt1988\PlatformGame\Helpers
{
}
```

How do i/Can i do this?

Was struggling to find anything in google

**EDIT:**

Considering this is a "duplicate" and was **unfindable in google**... I suggest you re-tag/name/whatever the "duplicate" entry.

Comment: Stay unhappy and have three lines beginning with namespace and have the the three closing '}'

Comment: Goddddd dammitttt leeroyyyy. Thanks @DieterLücking

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28022457/3014695) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @pkrysiak - You have brought upon me depression and distaste :D ... C++17 <cries>

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - c'mon, It's like only 2 years to go ;)

Comment: I'm coding with Unreal engine, cross platform is apparently a big deal... and C++17 is not... going to cut it with their code base. Damn them, damn the world... arrrr... Thanks guys

Comment: "I suggest you re-tag/name/whatever the "duplicate" entry." — That's not how duplicates work. This question, marked as duplicate, *will stick around **exactly so that it provides more findability** for the other question*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i do this?

No.  The closest you can get is

```
namespace Jimmyt1988{ namespace PlatformGame{ namespace Helpers

}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no abbreviated form in C++ for nested namespaces. I prefer one of the following depending on consistency:

```
namespace X
{
namespace Y
{
namespace Z
{
    // Avoid nesting too deep.
```

Or all on one line (slightly less clear but keeps a bunch of separate lines combined.

```
namespace X { namespace Y { namespace Z {
```