# C2143 syntax error when including boost/optional.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, option-type, boost-optional

I'm stuck with a compile-time error which I cannot understand. I try to use `boost::optional` in my code, and as soon as I include `boost/optional.hpp` I cannot build my project any longer. If I comment this include statement out, it works. I don't even have any actual usage of `boost::optional` in my code yet, just the include statement in the class header (see full header below). The compiler error is `C2143 syntax error: missing ',' before '<'` which happens in another Boost header `boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp` (see GitHub link below). I also successfully use other stuff from Boost like `boost::filesystem::path` in the same project already, so there should be no problem with my Boost distribution as such.

Here is my environment: `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3` and `boost 1.62.0`. I also use the third-party library [C++ REST SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk), everything else is C++ standard library stuff.

My header looks like this. I want to add a new method with `boost::optional<size_t>` as return type.

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/optional.hpp>   // <==== ERROR

// C++ REST SDK
#define _TURN_OFF_PLATFORM_STRING
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>
#include <cpprest/http_msg.h>

namespace SANDBOX::REST
{
   class HttpGetHandler
   {
   public:
       virtual void HandleHttpGetRequest(web::http::http_request request) = 0;
   };
}
```

The place, where the compiler error is reported, is in the Boost header `boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp`, line 36. You can view the full content of this file on GitHub under https://github.com/boostorg/utility/blob/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp

The compiler output shows nothing more than these messages:

```
1>D:\dev\lib\boost_1_62_0\boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp(36): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
1>  D:\dev\lib\boost_1_62_0\boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp(40): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::equal_pointees_t<OptionalPointee>' being compiled
1>D:\dev\lib\boost_1_62_0\boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp(59): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
1>  D:\dev\lib\boost_1_62_0\boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp(63): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::less_pointees_t<OptionalPointee>' being compiled
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It's surely not a problem of the Boost library. But how can I figure out, what's wrong with my classes or project settings?

P.S. I can reproduce the behavior even if I use these most primitive header and source file in my project:

Header file `Test.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/optional.hpp>
```

Source file `Test.cpp`:

```
#include "../include/Test.h"
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).  Also post **text**, not pictures.

Comment: Show us the exact line that triggers the error, and please edit your question to include the code as text, not screenshots. Also, `std::binary_function` is deprecated.

Comment: In addition to "stop posting pictures, I can't copy/paste them to repro", in regards with "so there should be no problem with my Boost distribution as such.": be it as it may, it won't hurt to specify what version of boost you are using.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall This deprecated usage comes from the Boost header, not from my code.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi My boost version is 1.62.0, it's mentioned in the text.

Comment: Show us the source file where you include this header file.

Comment: Note that you might get a better response on the boost mailing list.

Comment: @MartinBonner Hi Martin, I added a very simple header and source example to the description, which already give me this error.

Comment: Bother.  The usual reason for a weird compilation error in well-tested libraries like boost is a problem in an earlier header.  Are you using precompiled headers?

Comment: @MartinBonner No, I do not use precompiled headers as far as I know. I don't blame Boost, of course, it's surely my own problem. My question is - how to find out, which of my classes triggers the error? The only thing I see in the compiler output is this: `D:\dev\lib\boost_1_62_0\boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp(36): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
    D:\dev\lib\boost_1_62_0\boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp(40): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::equal_pointees_t<OptionalPointee>' being compiled`

Comment: Is it possible that you are using `/std:c++latest`? I understand this switch removes some of the things that will be removed in c++17 and it's possible that Boost (or this particular Boost library) has not adapted yet to that change. If  you are using it you should try `/std:c++14` and see if it works for you.

Comment: @jv_ YES! That's it! I use `/std:c++latest` to enable C++17 one-line nested namespace definition. If I remove `/std:c++latest`, I can use `boost::optional` without any problems. Man, that was a great hint! Please enter it as solution and I will upvote it and mark as answer!

Comment: @jv_ Please enter your comment as answer to this question, because this was the solution for my problem. I will upvote it and mark it as accepted answer. Otherwise I will enter an answer myself, becasue this may be helpful to other people dealing with the same issue, Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to make an answer yourself, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could figure out the reason due to a valuable hint by [jv_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2417774/jv). I turned on compiler switch `/std:c++latest` in my project settings to be able to use C++17 [nested namespace definition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html) feature. Activating this switch removes some deprecated language features, in particular `std::binary_function`, which is still in use in the current Boost distribution (1.62.0), hence producing the compiler error. Finally, I decided to remove the switch `/std:c++latest` (and use the ordinary way to declare my namespaces) and this solved the issue. Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: I was also able to compile still using `/std:c++latest` by simply removing the inheritance from `std::binary_function` in the `equal_pointees_t` and `less_pointees_t` struct templates in my copy of compare_pointees.hpp. This may be a good workaround if you really want to use C++17 features before Boost removes the deprecated usage themselves.

Answer (score 4):

The problem fixed in boost 1.63.0. It no longer uses `std::binary_function` which is removed in C++17.

Comment: Yes, I can definitely confirm this statement. With `boost 1.63.0` I can use the `/std:c++latest` switch along with `boost/optional.hpp` without any problems.

Comment: Unfortunately there's another use of `std::unary_function` in boost\algorithm\string\detail\util.hpp (boost version 1.64). :-(

Comment: And there's also a use of  `std::unary_function` and a use of  `std::binary_function` in `boost\icl\type_traits\predicate.hpp`. (version 1.65)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a #define new DEBUG_NEW in the Force include file (C++->Advanced).
I fixed it by adding a #undef new berore the boost #include's and then #define new DEBUG_NEW after.