# Resolving namespace conflicts

Tags: c++, namespaces

I've got a namespace with a ton of symbols I use, but I want to overwrite one of them:

external_library.h

```
namespace LottaStuff
{
class LotsOfClasses {};
class OneMoreClass {};
};
```

my_file.h

```
using namespace LottaStuff;
namespace MyCustomizations
{
class OneMoreClass {};
};
using MyCustomizations::OneMoreClass;
```

my_file.cpp

```
int main()
{
    OneMoreClass foo; // error: reference to 'OneMoreClass' is ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

How do I get resolve the 'ambiguous' error without resorting to replacing 'using namespace LottaStuff' with a thousand individual "using xxx;" statements?

Edit: Also, say I can't edit my_file.cpp, only my_file.h.  So, replacing OneMoreClass with MyCustomizations::OneMoreClass everywhere as suggested below wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Here's a tip - DON'T use the "using" keyword but instead refer to classes with their fully qualified names: vector<> -> ::std::vector<> !

Comment: C++11 will have a nice feature for versioning namespaces (inline namespace) that will allow the user to get exactly this... then again, you might need to wait more than you want for the feature to be in your compiler (unless you are using gcc >4.4) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2535.htm

Comment: See also [How do you properly use namespaces in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The entire point of namespaces is defeated when you say "`using namespace`".

So take it out and use namespaces. If you want a using directive, put it within main:

```
int main()
{
    using myCustomizations::OneMoreClass;

    // OneMoreClass unambiguously refers
    // to the myCustomizations variant
}
```

Understand what `using` directives do. What you have is essentially this:

```
namespace foo
{
    struct baz{};
}

namespace bar
{
    struct baz{};
}

using namespace foo; // take *everything* in foo and make it usable in this scope
using bar::baz; // take baz from bar and make it usable in this scope

int main()
{
    baz x; // no baz in this scope, check global... oh crap!
}
```

One or the other will work, as well as placing one within the scope for `main`. If you find a namespace truly tedious to type, make an alias:

```
namespace ez = manthisisacrappilynamednamespace;

ez::...
```

But *never* use `using namespace` in a header, and probably never in global scope. It's fine in local scopes.

Answer (score 3):

You should explicitly specify which `OneMoreClass` you want:

```
int main()
{
    myCustomizations::OneMoreClass foo;
}
```

Comment: what if I can't edit my_file.cpp though?  edited my question above.

Comment: @Kyle: Then stop using `using namespace`. You can't use that then complain about namespace conflicts. That's like having seat-belts in your car, but you rip them out then complain you're not safe.