# I'm in trouble with inheritance and polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to C++, and I'm trying to use inheritance but I have an error.
It says

> Error 6   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   L:\2011-08\C++\Assignment\Drug Management\Debug\Drug Management.exe 1   1   Drug Management

There're three classes which are Animal, Sheep, and Cattle.
What I've done so far is:

```
//Animal.h
#ifndef ANI_H
#define ANI_H
#include <string>
#include "Treatment.h"
#include "jdate.h"

class Animal{
protected:
    int id;
    double weight;
    int yy;
    int mm;
    int dd;
    double dose;
    char sex;
    //Treatment treatArray[];
public:
    Animal();
    Animal(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, double newdose, char newsex);
    ~Animal();
    virtual double calcDose();
    //void addAnimal();
    double getDaysDifference();
};
#endif

//Cattle.h
#ifndef CATT_H
#define CATT_H
#include "Animal.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Cattle : public Animal{
private:
    string category;
public:
    Cattle();
    Cattle(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, 
           double newdose, char newsex, string newcategory);
    ~Cattle();
    virtual double calcDose();
    string getCategory();
};

#endif

//Animal.cpp
#include "Animal.h"

using namespace std;

Animal::Animal(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, double newaccDose, char newsex)
{
    id = newid;
    weight = newweight;
    dose = newaccDose;
    sex = newsex;
}

double Animal::getDaysDifference(){
    jdate dateOfBirth(dd,mm,yy);
    jdate now;
    double diff = now-dateOfBirth;
    return diff;
}


//Cattle.cpp
#include "Cattle.h"



Cattle::Cattle(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, 
           double newdose, char newsex, string newcategory)
    : Animal(id, weight, yy,mm,dd, dose, sex)
{
    id = newid;
    weight = newweight;
    dose = newdose;
    sex = newsex;
    Cattle::category = newcategory;
}

string Cattle::getCategory(){
    return category;
}

double Cattle::calcDose(){
    Cattle* c1;
    if(c1->getDaysDifference() < 90 || c1->getCategory() == "Meat"){
        c1->dose = 0;
        return c1->dose;
    }
    else if(c1->getCategory() == "Dairy"){
        if (c1->weight < 250 || c1->dose > 200){
            c1->dose = 0;
        }
        else{
            c1->dose = c1->weight * 0.013 + 46;
        }
        return c1->dose;
    }
    else if(c1->getCategory() == "Breeding"){
        if (c1->weight < 250 || c1->dose > 250){
            c1->dose = 0;
        }
        else{
            c1->dose = c1->weight * 0.021 + 81;
        }
        return c1->dose;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It is not valid category" << endl;
    }
}
```

Sheep class is pretty much same as Cattle.
I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.
What I'm trying to do is inherit (or polymorphism) calcDose() in Cattle.cpp taking from Animal.h.
Can you give me a piece of advice?

Cheers

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I very much doubt that is the complete error message.  The complete message should say which externals are unresolved.

Comment: Yes there was another error message but I didn't put it because it was too long.. but thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared but did not define a default constructor and a destructor for Animal, and for Cattle (and presumably the others as well). Define them, or don't declare them (you probably do need a destructor though, even if it does nothing).

Another problem is your `calcDose` method. One way to deal with that is to make it "pure virtual" in Animal: use `virtual double calcDose() = 0;`

One final problem: Don't use `use namespace std;`. Don't ever, ever, ever use it in a header file.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's all sorted out now!
It was my first question in stackoverflow, but I think I have to ask here more often! You guys are so kind. Thanks :D

Comment: But, can I ask why I should not use namespace std in a header file?
I won't use it, but I'm just curious

Comment: @jcarlos: The standard library defines lots and lots of names, some of them very common names. An issue: How to protect against conflicts with user code? The solutions are (1) The C solution: Tough luck. Conflicts happen. (2) Make those names restricted keywords, or (3) Put them in their own namespace where conflicts can't happen. The C++ community chose option #3. Using `use namespace std;` puts you into the realm of option #1. Also see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.5 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c .

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your program's code, or without you specifying which symbols the linker couldn't find, it's hard to say exactly which symbols it's complaining about, but Animal is missing implementation for 3 of its member functions, and Cattle is missing implementation for 2 of its member functions.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared calcDose inside your Animal class, but you haven't defined it.  If you intended for that just to be implemented in the derived classes, then you should make it be pure virtual in your Animal class like this:

```
virtual double calcDose() = 0;
```