# Qt app 64-bit architecture error

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm working on Qt and adding slots to my Qt Gui application is giving out the following error.

```
 symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64.
```

when i comment out the `slots` block everything seems fine.

```
public slots:
```

Is there some kind of bug in QtCreator or am I doing something wrong.

I'm using Qt Creator 2.5.2 based on Qt 4.8.3(64-Bit) on Mac Osx 10.8 (mountain lion)

`Edit:` Here is my full class

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "qextserialport.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QextSerialPort *port;

public slots:
    void onDataAvailable();
};
```

Comment: Please quote the whole class declaration that contains the "public slots:"  One thing we shall be looking out for is the correct use of Q_OBJECT declaration.

Comment: @DarrylMiles I have edited the question with full class declaration.

Comment: Are you sure your use of namespace Ui is correct?  what happens if you remove 'class MainWindow;' and move the closing brace of the namespace to the last line ?  Or maybe you change 'class MainWindow ...' to 'class Ui::MainWindow ...' an incorrect namespace will cause symbol resolution failure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with namespace.I made several other apps this way and there was no problem.The error comes only when I add slots.Anyway I did what you said and there's "unknown type name 'MainWindow' error

Comment: But the type is Ui::MainWindow is not it (so therefore MainWindow will be unknown) ?  Does this link help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c

Comment: Post complete link error message. Not just the summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, it seems you didn't implement your slot function. So that would explain it.

If you did, then you might have to delete the makefile and regenerate it:

```
make distclean
qmake
```

So that the moc rules are updated.

Comment: Holyyy ....... You are right. The error's name,that completely confused me.Thought it was some Mac OsX architecture related problem. Thanks :)