# C++0x Threads and Sockets

Tags: multithreading, sockets, c++11, bind

i am writing an c++ programm (for arm-architecture) that connects to a CAN-Interface.
I'm using the standard socket, bind, recv and send function for this.
Now i am at the point where i need to outsource some functions into threads. 
For that i would like to use the C++0x Threads because i read here somewhere that the pthreads should not be used within c++ due compatibility problems.

So i includes the thread-library `#include <thread>` . and added to my compiler call the options `-Wno-psabi -std=c++0x -lpthread`

(`-Wno-psabi` is there to disable the `note: the mangling of ‘va_list’ has changed in GCC 4.4` message)

The error i get is:

`25: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘std::bind(_Functor, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Functor = int, _ArgTypes = sockaddr*, unsigned int](((sockaddr*)(&((can*)this)->can::addr)), 16u) < 0`

`/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.4.5/system_error:258: note: candidates are: bool std::operator<(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_condition&)`

`/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.4.5/system_error:177: note:                 bool std::operator<(const std::error_code&, const std::error_code&)`

I think that the bind function from the thread library is overriding the bind function from the sockets.

How can i tell the compiler when to use what function?

im using the `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++` version 4.4.5

Comment: Try using `::bind` for the C function, or don't use `using namespace std` and fully qualify your `std` function calls.

Comment: ::bind works.
but im going to qualify my `std` function calls. thank you!

if you could post this as an answer i will tag it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `::bind` for the C function, or don't use `using namespace std` and fully qualify your std function calls.

There are also intermediate solutions, see:

- [How do you properly use namespaces in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c)
- [namespace in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/)