# Namespaces and their uses

Tags: c++, oop, namespaces

What are the advantages of: 
1) namespaces 
2) including headers in a namespace 
3) reverse of " using " namespace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Namespaces avoid naming conflicts in complex projects.**

For example the boost library and the standard library both have a class `regex` and a class `thread`.  Without namespace, you couldn't use both libraries together.  With namespace you can specify the name, for example:  `boost::regex` and `std::thread`.

Another example, is when you have several versions of code that coexist.  This [article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2013.html) shows a nice example for libraries, using nested namespaces and appropriate `using` statemens.

**2) Namespace accross source files**

Declaration/definition need not to be contiguous. You could have several blocks of namespace in source files, refering to the same namespace.  So no problem  of using in headers or in bodies.

Example: 
File *source.h*

```
namespace cth {
    void doSomethingGreat();    // forward declaration
}
```

File *source.cpp*

```
#include "Source.h"
int main()  // not in the cth namespace !  
{
    cth::doSomethingGreat();  // use what has been declared in the header
}
namespace cth {
    void doSomethingGreat( ) {     // define the function of the header
        // ... something great here 
    }
}
```

If you forget the namespace for the definition of the function for example, you will have linking errors.

Now you could include the header after the opening of a namespace.  It's valid, but remember that your compiler will include the file and handle it as if its content would be written where you included it.  And this might give surprising results.

For example if I change slightly the code in *source.cpp*  so that it starts like this:

```
namespace cth {
#include "Source.h"
    // ... something other stuff here  

}
```

Well it would work, but the definition in the header will be understood as a ***nested namespace***.  Thus the file will not compile, because the function `cth::doSomethingGreat()` has no forward declaration before `main()`.  But  the header would define  `cth::cth::doSomethingGreat()`.

If you follow the principle that a header file is something that should be used publicly,  you should make it self contained in terms of namespace.

**3) The using namespace facilitates the work.**

In the first example, you could have:

```
using boost::regex; 
using std::thread;
```

If later you change your mind,  you could change the using in your source code to switch to the other class  (if they use the same API, otherwhise, more work would be required !).

You can define a `using` in any block of code, and it applies until the end of the block. 
You can add several using in the same block for the same name, but it's illegal if it creates an ambiguity.

```
using cth::doSomethingGreat;
doSomethingGreat();   // will use cth::doSomethingGreat
using oth::doSomethingGreat;   // allowed 
doSomethingGreat();  // ERROR if same signature:  compiler doesn't know if he should use the cth:: or oth:: function.
```

But you can have different using n different blocs:

```
{
    using cth::doSomethingGreat;
    doSomethingGreat();  // use what has been declared in the header
}
{
    using oth::doSomethingGreat;
    doSomethingGreat();  // use what has been declared in the header
}
```