# c++ class implementation with string function

Tags: c++, class

I need to implement a class for one of my assignment and one of the function in the class that has string as datatype doesn't work

my definition code is :

```
#include <string>  
class expression {
public:
    expression();
    void promptUser();
    int getNum1();
    int getNum2();
    int calculate();
    st::string str;
    string numToString(int num);
    string opToString();

private:
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char op;
};
```

And in my implementation file 
when I try to definite `numTostring`

```
string expression::numToString(int num) {
    string digit;
    ...
```

It says that the declaration is incompatible with the header file(my class definition)

I have no idea why because both the function heading are the same.

the header file of expression.cpp( the implementation file) are :

```
#include "expression1.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
```

Comment: Try making a short example all in one file that demonstrates the problem.  Only include enough code to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your class uses the unqualified name `string`, but there is no `string` data type defined in any enclosing scopes. There's a *`std::string`* data type defined in namespace `std`. That's looks to be the type that you need:

```c++
std::string str;
std::string numToString(int num);
std::string opToString();
```

You can keep from having to type out `std::` everywhere by specifying a `using` statement:

```
using std::string;
```

But you might not want to do that inside a [header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575799/using-namespace-std-in-a-header-file), so stick with fully qualifying the type.

Comment: can i use include for string ?

Comment: @mathilde What do you mean by that?

Comment: @RichardHodges You're right, he shouldn't be using `using` inside headers. I'll update.

Comment: it is in french.. but is basicly says the function definition is incompatible with the <error type> expression::numTostring etc

Comment: @mathilde Make sure you are defining the function with the same return type and parameter declaration as the one in the expression1.h header file.

Comment: @0x499602D2 it is exactly the same as in the header file it is only my string functions that won't work but i did everything you told me.. put the std::String before in the header file then #include <string> and using namespace std for the implementation i still have the same message

Comment: @0x499602D2 i actually moved #include <iostream> and #include <string> before #include "expression1.h" and the error message stopped i guess it was only that thank you so much for helping me everyone

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use , you need to refer to it with std::

For example, your expression class declares:

```
st::string str;
string numToString(int num);
string opToString();
```

Which should be:

```
std::string str; // you typed st:: instead of std::
std::string numToString(int num); // lack of std::
std::string opToString(); // lack of std::
```

If you dont use 2 files (cpp + h) to define and declare your class then you can add line

```
using namespace std;
```

just after your includes. This way you wont have to type std:: each time you try to refer to string and similar types. However, using this is often called a bad "beginner" practice.

If you do use cpp+h then just add std:: before every string type and add using namespace std; to your cpp file.

If you want to know more then read: 
1. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/ 
2. [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) 
3. [How do you properly use namespaces in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to move

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

up so it is the first header included. The compiler ignores everything that comes before that magic line.