# c++ using stl vector

Tags: c++, stl, namespaces, std

I am a little confused about the use of vector. We usually type

```
#include <vector>
```

first. Then why we still need to attach the name space of vector when using it, like:

```
std::vector<int> a;
```

Why not just

```
vector<int> a;
```

Comment: What if you need to use both this `vector` and some Math library's `vector` class?

Comment: First, I think you should determine the difference between an include statement and a namespace.

Comment: please refer to this thread (to get you started) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You might want to learn more about *header files* and namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. More clear now. So it seems "include statement" doesn't specify the path to call the library. Need to review more why c++ separate these two processes.

Comment: Because its name is `std::vector`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you properly use namespaces in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `#include` directive including something from the C++ standard library "loads" the entities into the `std` namespace (or some other namespace like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1)).

The namespace helps preventing *global namespace pollution* - by keeping everything in a seperate namespace, identifier collisions are rendered impossible.

In the `<vector>` file, then there is something like

```
namespace std {
    template<typename T> class vector {
        ...
    };
}
```

As you see, the `vector` template is still in the `std` namespace.

In summary, you use an `#include` preprocessor directive to use some facility provided in a header file. The file's contents textually replace the `#include` directive.
Still, these facilities are in a different namespace to prevent name clashing.

Answer (score -2):

Namespaces were created to avoid collisions in naming. You might have something else as `vector` in your code. However you can use `using namespace std;` - it would allow you to use it like this (and anything else in std namespace): `vector a;` (of course if there is no name collision)

Comment: dont do `using namespace std`, just `using std::vector` is enough

Comment: For serious programs `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice. Here is an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice